# Why was Ant-Man excluded from the Civil War trailer?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, trailers

Has there been any official word on why Ant-Man, who we know from promotional images and the Ant-Man stinger sequel hook to be involved in Captain America- Civil War, was excluded from the recently released trailer for Civil War? Everyone else, even minor characters like Clint/Hawkeye were in it, as well as a yet unpromoted Black Panther, but Scott was left out.

This is weird considering **Ant-Man** was the last MCU movie before Civil War, and how the Ant-Man stinger set up his inclusion. The stinger was actually taken from Civil-War filming dailies! What was the reason for excluding Ant-Man after the work done to include him in the Civil-War story?

Comment: It's only the first trailer for a film that's more than half a year away. Isn't it a bit too soon to ask this?

Comment: @Walt every other player is included, Ant-Man's exclusion is glaring in comparison. Clint and War machine were included when Scott was not! It's weirding me out.

Comment: @cde, that way wonderwoman has been left out from the batman-superman movie. We know she's in it too. I guess it is just so that everything about the movie and its characters is not given out in the trailer itself.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmiad.png , anyways i also think its quite unnecessary to ask this now, same happened to WW in dawn of justice teaser trailer as mentioned by Barry and we have not even seen Aquaman yet. On the side note spider-man also not in the trailer and list can go on.

Comment: They would have definitely kept it for the next trailers, as this one already had so much to be excited about! You asking about AntMan, but they did not even show Vision in the trailer. And the news is, there will be a cameo by Spiderman too, and I do not think Ant Man and spider man would have huge roles in the movie, not mor ethan 5-10 min I guess

Comment: He isn't excluded from the final trailer. -- This is the final trailer released for Captain America: Civil War https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdTgRWiWCWU The following characters are shown (in order of appearance in this trailer). * Bucky Barnes / Winter Soldier
* Steve Rogers / Captain America
* Sam Wilson / Falcon
* Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow
* Thaddeus Ross
* Wanda Maximoff / Scarlet Witch
* T'Challa / Black Panther
* Tony Stark / Iron Man
* Lieutenant Col. James Rhodes / War Machine
* Vision
* Clint Barton / Hawkeye
* **Scott Lang / Ant-Man**
* Brock Rumlow / Crossbones
* Peter Parker

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong. Everybody was mentioned in Civil War trailer, unlike other Marvel trailers. Ant-man was mentioned twice.
[image]
[image]
Most of the Marvel trailers don't include new unexpected heroes or abilities, so it's strange that they included everybody.

Comment: You're wrong. This wasn't the trailer in question.

Comment: @cde And what are you asking? The question is "Why was Ant-Man excluded from the Civil War trailer?
"